# Render HTML conditionally in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there any tag which lets to render the HTML blocks conditionally. For e.g.: Struts has:

```
<logic:present name="someForm" property="someProperty">
    //Code block
</logic:present>
```

For e.g.: JSF has:

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty someList}">
    //Some code block
</h:panelGrid>
```

Is there anything like that in spring MVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plain old JSTL to your rescue!

The beauty of Spring MVC is that it doesn't add tons of redundant tag libraries unlike other frameworks. You can always rely on JSTL for such checks which is part of the JSP spec now.

```
<c:if test="${not empty someList}">

</c:if>
```

Comment: Yes, I know that I can use JSTL, but I did not know that spring mvc does not have such thing it self, but now I know. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

[The JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html):

```
<c:if test="${!empty someForm.someProperty}">

</c:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use the common JSP/JSTL taglibs

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<c:choose>
        <c:when test="${condition}">
            something
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            something else
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

alternatively

```
<c:if test="${condition}">
        something
    </c:if>
```

using c:if there is no else condition as far as i know