# Spring profile page dilema

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mapping

I'm  new to this website- I have looked at the rules for posting and also searched the website for my particular query and was unable to find anything useful.

We have a college project using Spring and Java, for each user that signs up they should get their own profile with display name some other info and a profile image which I have implemented. Now I am trying to implement a friend system. So a user can search for other users (which are stored on the mysql database by username). Search results can be >1, and whoever's name you click on it should take you to their profile page - where it has an invite to be friends button, once they click this button it sends this user an email stating they have a friend request. If they accept the invite something gets added to my database otherwise nothing happens.

My question is how do I implement dynamic request mappings so whoever's name I click on I go to their profile? (redirecting to the same jsp though)
And the last question if I am already friends with someone how do I hide the invite to friends button? and if I am on my own profile how would I hide the button too

I've been stuck on this for many days and have no idea how to get around it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how do I implement dynamic request mappings so
>   whoever's name I click on I go to their profile?

There are many ways to accomplish this. How about just tacking a parameter onto the url like: `http://server/page?profileId=12345`

> if I am already friends with someone how do I hide the invite to
>   friends button?

Use a conditional statement. See the answers to this question: [Render HTML conditionally in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815464/render-html-conditionally-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: How would I send a parameter to the URL are there any tutorials you can link? sorry I'm new to this I dont even know what to search for. Thanks

Comment: Within whatever page has a link to a user's profile, you would dynamically build that link. You would probably do this using basic string concatenation or interpolation, making use of a variable that contains the user ID of the user who's profile you want to link to.